# Javascript execute two functions at the same time with 1 (onclick event)

Tags: javascript, function, events

I need to execute two js functions at the same time with one onclick event 
When I click the square, the menu shows but at the same time the circle inside changes his color (in this moment I have to click twice) and when I click again the square, the menu goes away and the circle change again to his default color.

https://jsfiddle.net/7bnp14vq/31/

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function lightOn() {
  var x = document.getElementById('light');
  if (x.style.background === 'black') {
    x.style.background = 'gold';
  } else {
    x.style.background = 'black';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #0d0d0d;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  /*   background:blue; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-items {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-items:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #595959;
}

.nav-items:active {
  color: red;
}

.start-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #abbaab, #ffffff);
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.start-button-light {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /*   background:#0d0d0d;  */
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: inset 1px #bfbfbf;
  color: white;
}

#myDropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdown">

  <div onclick="myFunction(); lightOn()" class="start-button dropbtn">
    <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
      <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
document.getElementById("light").classList.toggle("on");`

Comment: As @mplungjan suggested toggling CSS classes is better, as it separates code from design.

Comment: Did everyone forget about `addEventListener`?  Combine the functions or use that twice.

Comment: @sqykly no I did not forget. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine code of both and use one function
use new  lightOn() I merged code for toggle in it.
All functions run sequentially so its better to run them in same block.

```js
function lightOn() {
  var x = document.getElementById('light');
  if (x.style.background !== 'gold') {
    x.style.background = 'gold';
     document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

  } else {
    x.style.background = 'black';
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #0d0d0d;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  /*   background:blue; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-items {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-items:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #595959;
}

.nav-items:active {
  color: red;
}

.start-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #abbaab, #ffffff);
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.start-button-light {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /*   background:#0d0d0d;  */
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: inset 1px #bfbfbf;
  color: white;
}

#myDropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdown">

  <div onclick=" lightOn()" class="start-button dropbtn">
    <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
      <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a new function to call the two functions:

```
function onClick() {
  myFunction();
  lightOn();
}
```

Then use the onClick function in your onclick attribute

```
<div onclick="onClick()" ...
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue here. It's an issue with his functions, not running them.

Comment: thanx for your help @Rob Brander

Answer (score 0):

Your `lightOn` function is not toggling correctly. `#light` does not have 'black' as a background to begin with, so you're off sync.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function lightOn() {
  var x = document.getElementById('light');
  if (x.style.background !== 'gold') {
    x.style.background = 'gold';
  } else {
    x.style.background = 'black';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #0d0d0d;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  /*   background:blue; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-items {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-items:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #595959;
}

.nav-items:active {
  color: red;
}

.start-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #abbaab, #ffffff);
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.start-button-light {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /*   background:#0d0d0d;  */
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: inset 1px #bfbfbf;
  color: white;
}

#myDropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdown">

  <div onclick="myFunction(); lightOn()" class="start-button dropbtn">
    <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
      <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes it does have background black. Look at the css. Also it’s id="light"

Comment: @mplungjan Yes it has a black background, but it would not be in `.styles`. You can only access style properties that have been set via the `style` attribute (unless you fetch the computed styles). Also thanks, I will update my answer with `#light`

Comment: Look at .start-button-light in the stylesheet

Comment: What should I see? What is the discussion? The circle was black and no need to “sync”

Comment: The background can not be read initially due to it being set in a stylesheet rather than inline. Because of this, on the first click the background is set to black via JS, this then means it can be read on the next click and it will display gold then. Meaning that it does not match up with the display of the dropdown. Bad choice of wording on my part with the "sync". @mplungjan

Comment: Ah, now I understand - my answer does not care, so I did not initially get what you meant!

Comment: However the test is != gold which is true

Comment: Yeah, exactly :) Sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: But that makes your comment not valid. If it is != gold to begin with, the script will set the value to gold and then the script will set it to black - no nothing is out of sync here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180375/discussion-between-profit-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just toggle classes?

NOTE: I removed the inline click too

```js
function toggleBoth() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("light").classList.toggle("on");
}
document.querySelector(".start-button").addEventListener("click",toggleBoth,false)
```

```css
* {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #0d0d0d;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  /*   background:blue; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-items {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-items:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #595959;
}

.nav-items:active {
  color: red;
}

.start-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #abbaab, #ffffff);
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.start-button-light {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /*   background:#0d0d0d;  */
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: inset 1px #bfbfbf;
  color: white;
}

#myDropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.on { background : gold}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdown">

  <div class="start-button dropbtn">
    <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
      <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact answer for which you're looking:

```
onclick="myFunction();lightOn();"
```

It's worth noting that there are more elegant ways to achieve this, where I think of elegant as accommodating possibly much more than two functions without compromising readability.

One such way is defining a new function, as mentioned earlier, like this:

```
function doBoth() {
    myFunction();
    lightOn();
}
```

Another is avoiding the `onclick` attribute entirely and instead binding event handlers to the DOM element directly, which is the preferred solution if you're a fan of *unobtrusive javascript*.

If they need to be sequential, then like this:

```
<a id="the-button" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        myFunction();
        lightOn();
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise, like this:

```
<a id="the-button" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", lightOn)
</script>
```